# Select unique combination of two fields in the db

Tags: mysql, select

I need to withdraw two fields: `Xsec` and `CondConfg` that I need to extract from the Database to populate a combo box. I already have two, very simple, separate queries to extract the fields:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Xsec FROM Table;
SELECT DISTINCT CondConfg FROM Table;
```

But I need to combine them to populate a single field. Trouble is, the `DISTINCT` fields do not overlap correctly, ie.

```
  Table
+------------------+
| Xsec | CondConfg |
| -----|-----------|
| 1.5  | abc       |
| 1.5  | abc       |
| 1.5  | def       |
| 2.5  | ghi       |
  etc......
```

What I need is:

```
  Table
+------------------+
| Xsec | CondConfg |
|------|-----------|
| 1.5  | abc       |
| 1.5  | def       |
| 2.5  | ghi       |
  etc......
```

`UNION` won't work because that simply groups them into a single column, and I need 2 separate columns as above.

I have done this before but it was so long ago that I have forgotten entirely, but I know there is a very simple solution to this.

Comment: No I need them side-by side. Sorry will edit the question

Comment: Are you looking for all combinations of Xsevc with CondConfig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assuming mysql supports cross joins:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Xsec FROM tbl) a
       CROSS JOIN 
       (SELECT DISTINCT CondConfg FROM tbl) b
```

That gives the cartesian product of the distinct value son the two tables.

But if you mean all existing combinations as opposed to all possible cobinations:

SELECT DISTINCT Xsec, CondConfg FROM tbl

Comment: works fine. just replace table1 and table2 with the same name.

Comment: `Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have it's own alias`

Comment: OK well I did try the second solution ( that's what I was looking for), but for some reason the first time I tried it gave me an error? Must have just had the wrong syntax. All working now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DISTINCT `Xsec`, `CondConfg` From Table1;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d66f7/1)